# Why does js_sys Promise::new require FnMut?

Tags: rust, promise, future, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

`js_sys` exposes JavaScript `Promise` via a function `pub fn new(cb: &mut dyn FnMut(Function, Function)) -> Promise;`. Per my reading of [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#parameters), there's nothing suggesting that the executor function will be called more than once, yet `js_sys` exposes it as an `FnMut` instead of an `FnOnce`.

Because of this, I can't wrap my head around a simple task, such as sending a message to myself in the future via a channel. Ideally, the `sender` half of the channel would be moved into the closure and `Promise::new` would accept an `FnOnce`.

```
async func send_to_future_self() {
  use std::sync::mpsc::{Sender, Receiver, channel};
  let (sender, receiver) = channel().split();

  // Schedule sending a message in the future

  // Option A: Move `sender` --> The closure becomes `FnOnce` because it consumes `sender`
  // Option B: Reference `sender` --> Then the borrow outlives `sender`'s lifetime

  let mut sleep_100 = move?? |accept: Function, _reject: Function| {
    // This Rust closure is exported to Javascript...
    let callback = Closure::__??__(move?? || {
      // Send a message via the channel
      sender.send(()).unwrap();
      let result = js_sys::Array::new();
      // Doesn't matter what value is passed here, it's just for synchronization
      result.push(&JsValue::from(true)); 
      accept.apply(&JsValue::undefined(), &result).unwrap();
    });

    web_sys::window().unwrap()
      .set_timeout_with_callback_and_timeout_and_arguments_0(
         callback.as_ref().unchecked_ref(), 
        100
      ).unwrap();
    // ... so intentionally forget it, otherwise it will be dropped at the end of this block 
    // despite JS still referring to it.
    callback.forget();
  };

  // Convert JS Promise into a Rust future
  // This wants an FnMut(Function, Function)
  let future: JsFuture = js_sys::Promise::new(&mut sleep_100).into();
  let _ = future.await;
  receiver.try_recv().unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that it gets wrapped as a JavaScript function object internally, which can be called multiple times (even though it won't be).

The simplest way you can get around this is by having your function be callable multiple times.  An easy way to do this is to wrap consumable values in `Option` and use [`Option::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) to get the value -- if you get back `None` then the function was called multiple times.

Here is some sample code illustrating this technique:

```
struct Consumable;

impl Consumable {
    fn consume(self) {}
}

fn requires_fnmut(_: impl FnMut()) {}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Some(Consumable);
    
    requires_fnmut(move || {
        let x = match x.take() {
            Some(v) => v,
            
            // If None we were called twice, so just bail.
            None => return,
        };
        
        x.consume();
    });
}
```

Here, `Consumable` is similar to `Sender` in your case: it exposes a method that consumes the receiver.  Calling this on a captured variable in a closure would make the closure implement `FnOnce` and not `FnMut`, as you have found yourself.

However, notice in `main()` that we wrap the `Consumable` in an `Option` and mark it `mut`:

```
let mut x = Some(Consumable);
```

Now we can "unwrap" this using `match x.take()` in the closure, returning from the closure if `take()` returns `None`, which would indicate that the function was called a second time.

After taking the value from the `Option` you are free to consume it.

---

It looks like in your question you have two nested closures, both of which need to be `FnMut`, and the inner one is what needs access to the `Sender`.  You can still use this approach, but you have to do the same thing in both closures to transfer the consumable value from the outer closure to the inner closure.  Here is an example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = Some(Consumable);
    //      ^ The outer closure takes ownership of this x.
    
    requires_fnmut(move || {
        let mut x = x.take();
        //      ^ The inner closure takes ownership of this x.
        
        if x.is_none() {
            // We were already called once.
            return;
        }
        
        requires_fnmut(move || {
            let x = match x.take() {
                Some(v) => v,
                
                // We were already called once.
                None => return,
            };
            
            x.consume();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: In your example, the lifetime of the mutable borrow of `x` can't outlive `x`, but with `js_sys::Promise::new`, the closure is going to be run asynchronously and so the borrow of `x` would outlive `x`.

Comment: @Huckle There is no borrowing if you move into the closure. In nested closures you can repeat the pattern -- `take()` into the outer closure and move the result into the inner closure. Or with nested `move` the compiler will do it for you.

Comment: (Nested `move` may not work as that will likely make the outer closure `FnOnce`. So `take()` at each level is probably what you want.)

Comment: @Huckle I've updated my answer with an example of using this technique to transfer a consumable value through two nested closures.

Comment: I'm looking closer at the function signatures and `Window::set_timeout_*` only require a JavaScript `Function`, rather than a Rust `Fn*`, so that actually simplifies things a bit. The `Closure` struct is a utility to help move between the two and it has an `FnOnce` and an `FnMut` version.

Comment: @Huckle Ah, nice. You can probably make it work using the `take()` trick only in the outer closure then.

Comment: [Rust Playground of working example w/ stubbed signatures](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cad807629d15a905f6cfdd7bbe875162).

Comment: @Huckle Nice. Note that your `if is_none()` followed by `take()` could be simplified to `take().expect("called twice")`.

Comment: Instead of wrapping the captured values in `Option` you could wrap the whole `FnMut` and keep the inner code the same, as in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b36043aea5cc31c000ed9b0049c01c61).

Comment: @rodrigo I had that thought as well, not a bad approach.